# How do I determine the audio format of a online stream?

Tags: java, linux, audio

I have an online audio stream at https://iceant.antfarm.co.za/EdenFM. You can simply paste the audio stream in your browser to hear the audio. My question is: "How do I determine the audio format of the stream? Can this be done with a Linux command?

Comment: Isn't the server supposed to send in the http headers the MIME type (audio/mpeg, audio/ogg, ...)? Without that, I don't think you can, a raw stream of bytes without other info is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`curl`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) by fetching only the header with the `-I` or `--head` option. The audio format can be determined based on the *Content-Type* in the response.

```sh
curl -I https://iceant.antfarm.co.za/EdenFM
```

With `grep` you can filter the relevant line:

```sh
curl -I -s https://iceant.antfarm.co.za/EdenFM | grep -i "^Content-Type:"
```

Which outputs this:

```
Content-Type: audio/aac
```

---

Of course this can be done in Java as well by sending a `HEAD` request to the desired endpoint:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://iceant.antfarm.co.za/EdenFM");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
con.connect();
String contentType = con.getContentType();

System.out.println(contentType);
// output: audio/aac
```

Here is a version with the new *HttpClient* in Java 11:

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://iceant.antfarm.co.za/EdenFM"))
        .method("HEAD", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
        .build();
HttpResponse<Void> response = client.send(request,
        HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());

HttpHeaders headers = response.headers();
headers.firstValue("Content-Type").ifPresent(System.out::println);
// output: audio/aac
```

*It might be possible that you need to overcome some additional hurdles with SSL/TLS certificates depending on the server, your Java version and other factors.*

Answer (score 1):

You tag your question with tag::Java but your question only mentions a shell command, so here you are:

```
$ curl -I https://iceant.antfarm.co.za/EdenFM
```

will get you:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: audio/aac
Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 13:33:16 GMT
icy-description:EDEN FM – Your Voice in Paradise
icy-genre:Various
icy-metadata:1
icy-name:EdenFM
icy-pub:1
Server: Icecast 2.4.0-kh13
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD
Connection: Close
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
```

The relevant line is of course:

```
Content-Type: audio/aac
```

That you can get with a grep.